# Google Sheets formula to place message in cell when range contains the text "0"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with three columns.  In Column A and B are two numbers, and in Column C is a formula to produce a ratio from those two numbers.  Here is that formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(round(B2/min(B2,C2),2)," : ",round(C2/min(B2,C2),2))
```

My problem is that sometimes one of these numbers is zero, and that causes the formula to produce the error:

```
Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be zero.
```

Self-explanatory.

**How can I change my formula to instead produce a ratio with a zero in it?  So for example:**

```
1.89 : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want:?

```
=CONCATENATE(if(C6=0,B6,round(B6/min(B6,C6),2))," : ",if(C6=0,"0",round(C6/min(B6,C6),2)))
```

Comment: It worked exactly as desired in the test spreadsheet, but not in my real one.  I think it has something to do with the fact that the referenced cells have a number format applied to them, but I found an easy workaround for that.  So it does what I want!  Thanks!